# how to convert any struct Variable list into a string in JSON format

Tags: c, paho

Is it possible to turn a dynamic pointer Struct into a string or a String in JSON format without

I'm trying to use the pahoMQTT functions to send data to a databroker which take a JSON format string, but I am getting always my program Name and the Process Variables List above the elements of the structure which I already know...
it's Like

my program Name ist MQTT.c and my Structure name is BrokerData:
struct BrokerData{
Uint ID,
int speed,
real angle
};

so i get

```
{
  MQTT:Broker
  {
    ID:10,
    speed:100,
    angle:50
}
```

i'm trying to use the snprint function, callloc and size_t, but because i'm using a PLC programming enviroment, i get a conflict in my program

so if there is any way to change my struct to a string that anyone knows, i'd be very grateful

Comment: Hello, Please read the guide on what a good SO question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask As it is your question needs a fair bit of [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68101650/edit) to make it clear what you are actually asking.

Comment: At runtime, variable names and names of struct members are unavailable. So if your program is not explicitly aware of them by other ways it is probably impossible even with using suitable libs. Please provide a [mre] of your programs data handling.